# Plotting sin wave with amplitude,frequency and phase angle

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, qtgui

I was trying to make sin wave of the type

```
f(x) = A*sin(2*pi*f*x + phi)
```

Where A is amplitude, f is frequency and phi is phase angle. I know to plot simple sin curve like this :

```
def plot(self):
    Amplitude = 1.5
    Frequency = 0.5
    Phase = 2.6
    ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
    X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 256,endpoint=True)
    S = np.sin(X)
    ax.hold(True)
    ax.plot(X, S, color="blue", linewidth=1.0, linestyle="-")
    xlim(0.0,2.0)
    xticks(np.linspace(0,2,5,endpoint=True))
    ylim(-1.5,1.5)
    yticks(np.linspace(-1.5,1.5,7,endpoint=True))
    self.canvas.draw()
```

I am drawing it using QtGui. Please help me find correct way to plot this sine wave.

I have an idea that I need to modify these two lines :

```
X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 256,endpoint=True)
S = np.sin(X)
```

My Try :

```
def plot(self):
    Amplitude = 1.5
    Frequency = 0.5
    Phase = 2.6

    fs = 44100
    T = np.arange(-0.002, .002, 1.0/fs)

    ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

    X = Amplitude*np.sin(2*np.pi*Frequency*T + Phase)

    ax.hold(True)
    ax.plot(T, X, color="blue", linewidth=1.0, linestyle="-")
    xlim(0.0,2.0)
    xticks(np.linspace(0,2,5,endpoint=True))
    ylim(-1.5,1.5)
    yticks(np.linspace(-1.5,1.5,7,endpoint=True))
    self.canvas.draw()
```

But nothing is displayed as sine wave now . Please help me find error.

Along X axis it lie from 0 to 2 like this 0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0

Along Y axis it lie from -1.5 to 1.5 like this -1.5,-1.0,-0.5,0.0,0.5,1.0,1.5

Comment: Have you tried altering anything?

Comment: @JRichardSnape Yeah, I tried many things, but one time or other some error comes up :(

Comment: Your x limits are set to between 0 and 2, but your actual x values are in the range -0.002 to 0.002.

Comment: @BySymmetry This fs is right ? fs = 44100

Comment: Your problem here it's mathematical, rather than programmatic. Your x axis here is time. You're trying to display an audio signal I guess as 44.1kHz it's standard audio sampling f. Just expand the range of T - use np.arange(0,2,1.0/fs). With f = 0.5 Hz and calculating /plotting 2 seconds, you should see one complete wave

Comment: @mat7 Has this solved your problem, or do you need more info?